# What is the definition of a stationary charge compared to a moving charge?

Tags: charge

A stationary charge produces an electric field and a moving charge produces a magnetic field.  What defines a stationary charge in this regard. Does it just mean that electrons are not flowing in a wire?  Or does it mean that electrons are not spinning around a nucleus or spinning in themselves?

Answer (score 1):

The term "stationary charge" indicates that you only need electrostatics to describe the system. That means that it only produces an electric field. So yes, in terms of electric circuits that means that electrons are not flowing in the wire.

The moving charge on the other hand will produce an electric field and a magnetic field.